# Method subtracting elements of array from average of array numbers

Tags: java, arrays, double, rounding

I have an array of type `double` that is filled from values that the user enters, these values are lap times for a swimming race. It stores the times in `lapArray` and I have a few methods but one calculates the average of all the numbers in `lapArray`. However, I have another method `getDeviationsArray` that is supposed to find out if the lap times are below the average or above the average and fill an array called `devArray` with these results.

Basically just subtracting each lap time from the average, however if the lap time is higher than the average I get a result of `0`. This could be my rounding but I want to get a negative result which would be a slower time.

This is my expected output:

[image]

I have the first four rows which my other methods `getFastest`, `getSlowest`, `getAverage`, and get `raceTime` have done already. I just need to properly subtract the laptimes from the average and then also find a way that If the laptime was more than the average that it should have a (`+`) sign and less than average has a (`-`) sign.

Code:

```java
public static double[] getDeviationsArray(Double[] inputArray) {
    double[] devArray = new double[inputArray.length];
    double diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (inputArray[i] < getAverageSplit(inputArray)) {
            diff = Math.abs(inputArray[i] - getAverageSplit(inputArray));
            devArray[i] = diff;
        } else {
            diff = Math.abs(getAverageSplit(inputArray) - inputArray[i]);
            devArray[i] = diff;
        }
    }
    return devArray;
}
```

```java
System.out.println("Here are the split-times and deviations for each lap/length:\n");
double[] devArray1 = getDeviationsArray(lapArray);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
int index1 = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < lapArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Lap or length #" + index1 + ": " + lapArray[i] + " seconds ("
            + Double.valueOf(df.format(devArray1[i])) + ")");
    index1++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like you are overcomplicating this. You should leave the negative diffs negative rather than using `abs` and then format with '+' sign:

```
double[] devArray = new double[inputArray.length];
double average = getAverageSplit(inputArray));
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; ++i) {
    devArray[i] = inputArray[i] - average;
}
```

Also be aware that this can be done with a stream operation which might be a bit more straightforward:

```
double[] devArray = Arrays.stream(inputArray).map(t -> t - average).toArray();
```

Then use the following code to format with a sign symbol and 2 decimals:

```
String.format("%+.2f", devArray[i])
```

Comment: The OP could use `System.out.printf` directly.  Another possible suggestion would be to use a fixed width format with leading zeros `%+06.2f`.  But it clearly is easier over `DecimalFormat`